# Calculating second derivatives with curves

Tags: differential-geometry

I always thought that the following is true:

> Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, $f \in C^2(M)$, and $X \in \Gamma(TM)$. Then
> $$ X^2f(x) = \frac{d^2}{dt^2} (f \circ \gamma)(0) $$
> for any curve $\gamma$ with $\gamma(0) = x, \gamma'(0) = X_x$.

Here, the LHS should be interpreted as $X_x(Xf)$ where $Xf$ is the function $x\mapsto X_xf$.

The LHS can be calculated in coordinates as
$$ X^2f = X(df(X)) = X(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}\, X^i) = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^i\partial x^j} X^i X^j + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial X^i}{\partial x^j}X^j,$$
where Einstein convention is used. On the other hand, the RHS is
$$ \frac{d^2}{dt^2} (f \circ \gamma)(0)
= \frac{d}{dt}\Bigg|_0 df_{\gamma(t)}(\gamma'(t)) = \frac{d}{dt}\Bigg|_0 ( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}\Bigg|_{\gamma(t)} \gamma'(t)^i) = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^i\partial x^j} X^iX^j + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i} \frac{d\gamma'(t)^i}{dt}\Bigg|_0.  $$
So the claim is true if one can show that
$$ \left( \frac{d^2}{dt^2} (x^i\circ\gamma)(0) \right) = \frac{d\gamma'(t)^i}{dt}\Bigg|_0= \frac{\partial X^i}{\partial x^j}X^j. $$
However, I don't see how one can show this, since it seems that we need to have some local information about the tangent field $\gamma'(t)$ around zero, which we don't given the assumptions. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to demand more on $\gamma$.

For example, let $M=\mathbb{R}$ and $X=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}$.  The curve $\gamma(t)=t+t^2$ would have $(f\circ\gamma)''(0)=\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}t^2}f(t+t^2)\vert_{t=0}=f''(0)+2f'(0)$ which is not $X^2f(0)=f''(0)$.

If $\gamma$ agrees with the integral curve of $X$ to second order, then indeed you have
$$
X^2f(x)=\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}t^2}(f\circ\gamma)(0).
$$

Comment: I thought something was missing :-) Thanks!